# Are cron jobs advisable to use as a vehicle for polling messages on AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We have a requirement that constantly need to check and pick up messages from SQS. The idea is process the messages asynchronously, so the processor has to pick up and process the messages in SQS.

Are cron jobs advisable to use as a vehicle for polling messages on AWS SQS?

If not, are there other patterns/approaches we could use?

Since we are using Java, we are also considering using JMS, but I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Cron is advisable if you require a periodic execution of X, because that's what's it good at.

However, it will only schedule the execution but what are you executing? The script/executable being run will do the *actual* work so you should concentrate on that performing correct operations.

Comment: Potentially, the trigger for execution are the messages from SQS. Thoughts on that?

Comment: So you have something running long polling and then perform actions when messages come in? Sure why not - depends on your use case.